# Should all key names be specified when tables join on Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Here are the example tables:
1. students
studentID -- PK
studentName
collegeID
2. colleges
collegeID -- PK
collegeName 

I wanted to get all of students key values and all of colleges key values

Here is the example sqlalchemy query.

```
from example.database import dao
    ...
    ...
    example = dao.query(students).\
          join(colleges, 
               students.collegeID == colleges.collegeID).\
          all()
```

but It didn't have collegeName data. only had students data.
So I had to change it.

```
example = dao.query(students.studentID, 
                students.studentName,
                stduents.collegeID,
                colleges.collegeName).\
          join(colleges, students.collegeID == colleges.collegeID).\
          all()
```

How can I do this easier and faster without specifying all keys I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
example = (dao.query(students, colleges)
    .join(colleges, students.collegeID == colleges.collegeID)
    ).all()

for student, college in example:
    print(student, college)
```

This will return a list of tuple values:

```
 <student-1, college-1>
 <student-1, college-2>
 ...
 <student-N, college-?>
```